# how to implement locale using ant design plugin in react application

Tags: reactjs, react-native, antd

I am trying to build application using ant design library. I have an application with home page and want to use localization so application uses locale from browser and displays accordingly. 
I searched ant design supports it but could not find example to see how its implemented. 
Any pointer or sample apps showing how its done will be really helpful.

Comment: <LocaleProvider locale={zhCN}>
            <Layout style={{width:'100%',height:'100%'}}>
            </Layout>
</LocaleProvider>

Comment: i tried to use locale around my layout component which has a tree component embedded but it still shows data in english by default even though I set language as chinese

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/ojp9m528yz

Comment: see above example how could we change to have the labels Select Date shown using locale too